# Wildcard search in Acumatica SOAP API export filter

Tags: web-services, acumatica

I am trying to use Acumatica web services to "Export" from screen CR302000 (Organization > Customer Management > Contacts).

Using a Filter with a `FilterCondition.Contain` condition I can limit the results to only those with `Phone1` field containing a certain string.

Now I want the phone number I'm filtering on to contain a wildcard. In the web interface using % as a wildcard character works. But when using the web services this doesn't work (no rows are returned).

My Filter:

```
Filter[] filters = new Filter[]
{
    new Filter()
    {
        Field = new Field()
        {
            FieldName = context.DetailsContact.Phone1.FieldName,
            ObjectName = context.DetailsContact.Phone1.ObjectName
        },
        Condition = FilterCondition.Contain,
        Operator = FilterOperator.And,
        Value = "283%9534"
    }
}
```

Which becomes this in the SOAP request:

```
<Filter>
    <Field>
        <FieldName>Phone1</FieldName>
        <ObjectName>ContactCurrent: 1</ObjectName>
    </Field>
    <Condition>Contain</Condition>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">283%9534</Value>
    <OpenBrackets>0</OpenBrackets>
    <CloseBrackets>0</CloseBrackets>
    <Operator>And</Operator>
</Filter>
```

Does anyone know if filtering with wildcards can be achieved using the web services API?

**Update:** The % wildcard almost works if I don't include a `ContactSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryContactID` command. It returns exactly one result that matches the wildcard search. But I need every result that matches, which is why I include `EveryContactID`

**Update 2:** Wildcard works fine for screen CR301000 (Leads) with `LeadSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryLeadID` command. Is this a bug in CR302000?

**Update 3:** Summarising the conversation in the comments of the accepted answer, CR301 and CR302 should both be able to filter by contact telephone with a wildcard, but due to some unknown bug, CR302 can't use wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're trying to filter on a field which is not part of the primary view. In CR301000 (Leads), the Contact *is* the primary view, so your filter works. More explanation on this is provided here: [Using filter with Customer screen in Acumatica API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221295/using-filter-with-customer-screen-in-acumatica-api/29243354#29243354)

Comment: Do you mean that if the field being filtered is not part of the primary view, I cannot use wildcards?

Comment: It has nothing to do with wildcards; you can't filter on this field at all the way you're trying to do it. Imagine a Sales Order which has a header and detail grid. You can set a filter on any field in the header, but the the filters you set on the sales order detail lines would not be applied to the primary select; only applied after the primary view has been selected, which is not what you want. Solution is to create a generic inquiry and use the GI through web services; do your GI on the Contact table...

Comment: @tjleigh are you with QGate? I responded to a similar inquiry via e-mail this morning

Comment: OK I understand. The strange thing is, that doesn't match the behavior I saw. As I said in the question, the Contain filter appeared to work perfectly when there was no wildcard. Only when using a wildcard did it break. Maybe I was mistaken though... (PS, I expect I'll see your email on Monday, thanks)

Comment: @tjleigh do you have a sample which shows filtering working when using FilterCondition.Equals on DetailsMainContact.Phone1? In my tests it will return every single business account, but phone number will be blank for all of them except the one which matches the filter...

Comment: @tjleigh this code uses the Contacts screen (CR302000) - there's no issue on this one, since the Contact record is the primary view. CR303000 is the issue, on this one BAccount is the primary view and main contact is a 1:1 link between BAccount and Contact.

Comment: I've been able to replicate this locally, but don't have an explanation at this point why it's working in one case but not the other. One thing is clear, the query that gets pushed to SQL Server has doubled wildcards, which shows that the system is adding the % for you when using FilterCondition.Contain - so you should never put it there manually.

Comment: @tjleigh There's indeed an inconsistency/bug with wildcards - it works with regular screens, but not with web services on top of generic inquiries. We found a workaround - define a Parameter field in the GI and set value on it to filter. Bug will be logged and resolved.