# Filtering an Export of Appointments by Customer ID with Acumatica API

Tags: acumatica

I would like to Export all upcoming Appointments for a customer in Acumatica.  I've created two filters for the Export command: one for the Customer ID and one for the date range.  The date range filter gets applied appropriately, but the Customer ID filter is ignored.  All upcoming Appointments for all Customers are returned.  For now, I am applying my own Customer ID filter to the results that are returned, but I think that will be really slow when there are a large number of upcoming appointments across all customers.  Here is my code:

```
Public Function GetUpcomingAppointmentList(ByVal customerID As String) As String()()
    Dim appt As SD300200Content = m_context.SD300200GetSchema()
    m_context.SD300200Clear()

    ' THIS FILTER IS IGNORED
    Dim customerFilter As Filter = New Filter()
    customerFilter.Field = appt.ServiceOrderHeader.CustomerID
    customerFilter.Condition = FilterCondition.Equals
    customerFilter.Value = customerID

    Dim dateFilter As Filter = New Filter()
    dateFilter.Field = appt.ScheduledDateAndTime.Date
    dateFilter.Condition = FilterCondition.GreaterOrEqual
    dateFilter.Value = Date.Today

    Dim searchfilters() As Filter = {customerFilter, dateFilter}
    Dim searchCommands() As Command = {appt.AppointmentRecords.ServiceCommands.EveryAppointmentNbr, appt.ServiceOrderHeader.CustomerID, appt.AppointmentRecords.Status, appt.AppointmentRecords.AppointmentNbr, appt.AppointmentRecords.ServiceOrderNbr, appt.ScheduledDateAndTime.Date, appt.ScheduledDateAndTime.StartTime, appt.Employees.EmployeeName}
    Dim searchResult As String()() = m_context.SD300200Export(searchCommands, searchfilters, 0, False, False)

    ' SINCE ABOVE CUSTOMER FILTER DOESN'T WORK, HAVE TO FILTER OUT OTHER CUSTOMERS
    Dim filteredResults As List(Of String()) = New List(Of String())
    Dim i As Integer, apptCustomer As String
    For i = 0 To searchResult.Length - 1
        apptCustomer = searchResult(i)(0)
        If apptCustomer = customerID Then
            filteredResults.Add(searchResult(i))
        End If
    Next

    Return filteredResults.ToArray()
End Function
```

I also thought I might apply something similar to the solution provided in [Using filter with Customer screen in Acumatica API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221295/using-filter-with-customer-screen-in-acumatica-api).  But it seems that would require a line like this:

```
appt.AppointmentRecords.ServiceOrderNbr.FieldName = appt.AppointmentRecords.ServiceOrderNbr.FieldName + "!" + appt.ServiceOrderHeader.ServiceCommands.FilterCustomerID.FieldName
```

but appt.ServiceOrderHeader.ServiceCommands doesn't have any "Filter" properties in it at all.  Is there any other way to filter by Customer ID for Appointments, or is there a problem with my code above?

One other interesting thing is that even though the Export is returning lots of results that don't match the CustomerID filter I'm trying to apply, the extra results it returns do not provide the actual CustomerID number.  Instead, appt.ServiceOrderHeader.CustomerID for the records that don't match the filter is returned as an empty string.

Comment: Not really clear, what common screen do you use, what the version ?

Comment: @acumember Sorry, I'm new to Acumatica and I'm not sure what you mean by "common" screen.  But the Acumatica screen I'm referencing for the API is SD300200 for Appointments. I know we have some customizations but I'm not sure if that screen is one of them. Our Acumatica version is Version 4.20.2063

Comment: Hello Eric, the screen SD300200 is not our from the box, looks like it's your own customized screen, acumatica doesn't provide screen with id SD300200. So, issue probably with your screen. Try to ask your developers who prepared screen. It's related to the data structure, keys, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the full answer, but here is what I've learned:

As hinted at in the answer you linked, filters prefer the base object on the screen.  When combining filters, pay close attention to the ObjectName of the fields you reference.  The "and" condition seems to only work when the ObjectName is the same!

Here is an example specifically relevant to code I had handy for CR.30.20.00 that attempts to filter by Contact Type (Employee, Contact, Etc) and last modified date.  Both fields are available in the "Contact" ObjectName, but if you use ContactCurrent for one of the object names, the AND is ignored and you get all the records based on one filter.

```
filters.Add(new AcumaticaWS.Filter
{
    Field = CR302000Schema.ContactSummary.Type,
    Condition = FilterCondition.Equals,
    Value = "Employee"
});
filters.Add(new AcumaticaWS.Filter
{
    //Field = WSTools.NewA4Field(CR302000Schema.DetailsSummary.CompanyName.ObjectName, "LastModifiedDateTime"), // different object name
    Field = WSTools.NewA4Field(CR302000Schema.ContactSummary.Type.ObjectName, "LastModifiedDateTime"), // works!
    Condition = FilterCondition.GreaterOrEqual,
    Value = "2015-04-01"
});
```

I have not worked with your screen, but if the CustomerID field is also available on the `appt.ScheduledDateAndTime.ObjectName`, then you may be in business.  Note too that a field is sometimes available even if it is not in the strongly typed schema - just like my LastModifiedDateTime example.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Stan.  Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.  For my customer filter, I tried setting the Field's ObjectName to appt.ScheduledDateAndTime.Date.ObjectName and its FieldName to "CustomerID", but I still got the same result - no error message, but the filter wasn't applied.  I also tried removing the date filter entirely to use only the CustomerID filter, but it still isn't applied in that case either.